# Bash Script - Crontab completing part of the bash script but not all

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

The below bash script runs every 10 mins on L1 and within the script is meant to generate a random password, then print that into a file, which is then copied to L2.

```
#!/bin/bash
targetFile="testfilegen2.log"
address="192.168.1.1"
netmask="255.255.255.0"
channel="1"
essid="GreRPi"
random=$(pwgen 13 -1)
        sudo echo "source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d" > "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "auto lo" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "auto wlan0" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "allow-hotplug wlan0" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "iface wlan0 inet static" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "address $address" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "netmask $netmask" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "wireless-channel $channel" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "wireless-essid $essid" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "wireless-mode ad-hoc" >> "$targetFile"
        sudo echo "wireless-key s:$random" >> "$targetFile"
        sleep 1
        scp "$targetFile" pi@192.168.1.1:~/.ssh/
        sudo service networking restart
```

Unfornaltey L1 doesn't seem to receive the new password but L2 does.

L1 Output

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/greenwich $ cat testfilegen2.log
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
wireless-channel 1
wireless-essid GreRPi
wireless-mode ad-hoc
wireless-key s:she5Bie1ojoon
```

L2 Output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/.ssh $ cat testfilegen2.log
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
wireless-channel 1
wireless-essid GreRPi
wireless-mode ad-hoc
wireless-key s:ez2eeCeich0oc
```

Any Suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the logs of the script, does it say "Permission denied" ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running the script as non-root user, redirection does not work with sudo, so instead try the following

```
sudo sh -c "echo source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d > $targetFile"
```

And likewise for double redirection.

Redirect the output and error of your script to a log file so that you know what is going wrong. To achieve that, do the following changes :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    {
    ...
    your script here
    ...
    } 2>&1 > /tmp/myScript.log
```

You can further run the script in debug mode, to step by step debug your script.

If you are SCPing again and again the same file, I suggest you check the modification time of the file on the remote machine to confirm whether the file has received the updates.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it is still doing the same

Comment: it doesn't come up with an error, it just doesn't update the testfilegen2.log on L1, but only updates testfilegen2.log on L2. I'm a bit confused on this one.

Comment: The target file actually gets created on L1 and is SCPed to L2, right ?
Also did you try checking the logs, because the script might run but it is supposed to throw errors because you are redirecting it with sudo.

Comment: With the cron logs there is two lines that keeps happening everytime the bash script is run: 'Feb 26 17:20:02 raspberrypi CRON[4595]: (pi) CMD (/etc/greenwich/gentest.sh)
Feb 26 17:20:12 raspberrypi CRON[4591]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)'

Comment: Right `"NO MTA installed, discarding output"` means that your script is producing output, but since you have no mailer installed it cannot mail you the output.  Read this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog

Comment: The first step is to understand what the problem is, and you need to know the logs for that. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Vikas Tiwari, the redirection happens as the current user *before* `sudo` runs. You need to open the file with `sudo`. This can be done with the `tee` program, which you only need to run *once*.

```
targetFile="testfilegen2.log"
address="192.168.1.1"
netmask="255.255.255.0"
channel="1"
essid="GreRPi"
random=$(pwgen 13 -1)
{
    echo "source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d"
    echo "auto lo"
    echo "auto wlan0"
    echo "allow-hotplug wlan0"
    echo "iface wlan0 inet static"
    echo "address $address"
    echo "netmask $netmask"
    echo "wireless-channel $channel"
    echo "wireless-essid $essid"
    echo "wireless-mode ad-hoc"
    echo "wireless-key s:$random"
} | sudo tee "$targetFile" > /dev/null
    sleep 1
    scp "$targetFile" pi@192.168.1.1:~/.ssh/
    sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it is still doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your file is copied on the destination it mean that is created on the source. No doubt here.
Seems that the "$targetfile" is created in a directory that you don't expect it to be in. Typical problem if the full path to the target is not specified.
Your script is located in "/etc/greenwich/" but when the cron launches it, then the current directory where the script run is the users home directory (in most cases) and the "$targetfile" is created in the current directory.

Please define the "$targetfile" with full path to where you want the file to be created in.